# "mountall: event failed" on startup

Tags: boot, startup

I have shrunk my root partition (/dev/sda1) and expanded my home partition (/dev/sda2) using the free space gained from the root partition.

Then, every time I boot my machine I get this error, "mountall: event failed." But, everything seems to run well. All partitions get mounted.

I do not think it comes from the swap partition for I have many times repartitioned it and no such error was showed.

Comment: Please paste the output of the following 2 commands:

sudo blkid; cat /etc/fstab

Comment: Okay, sudo blkid: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5707843/ &
cat /etc/fstab: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5707844/

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting the output you provided for reference here:

sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ubroot" UUID="d9007a77-fa58-4282-8eb0-eb71328965eb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="ubhome" UUID="25bcc4cd-6baa-449f-bbbf-889b4637f645" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="ubdata" UUID="edd58b38-c30c-41fb-9f73-c827b175523e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="0da8e621-d564-44a7-aeda-e52d175ed6f3" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram0: UUID="ba2e2409-7a9e-4c77-9f49-43a0052adba7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr1: LABEL="AHA Dialer" TYPE="iso9660"
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d9007a77-fa58-4282-8eb0-eb71328965eb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=25bcc4cd-6baa-449f-bbbf-889b4637f645 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /gudang di /dev/sda3 oleh apg
UUID=edd58b38-c30c-41fb-9f73-c827b175523e /gudang         ext4    defaults        0        2
# swap was on /dev/sda4
UUID=0da8e621-d564-44a7-aeda-e52d175ed6f3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Your fstab looks correct given the available filesystems.

I've read a bit on the problem mountall is trying to solve and it looks to be utilized by plymouth (graphical boot splash) to fsck and mount partitions and swap devices "when they become available".

I've checked the contents of an intramfs images generated on a fresh install of 12.04 and I couldn't find any references to mountall, so I assume that it is invoked after mounting your root partition and there are references to it in /etc/init/mountall*.

If `cat /proc/swaps` shows `/dev/sda4` as being used and `mount` shows all partitions defined in `/etc/fstab` mounted (as you confirmed), I don't think you have much to worry about.

Unfortunately I'm not sure at which point in the code this message "event failed" is generated (I've only briefly looked at mountall's code). I've seen someone "fix" this issue by disabling, recreating and enabling the swap partition.

I'd try that just in case it is corrupted (and it doesn't hurt anyway, as long as /dev/sda4 is indeed your swap partition) by running:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo mkswap -l swap /dev/sda4
sudo blkid | grep swap
```

and adding the new swap UUID to /etc/fstab (or rather, replacing the existing UUID)

PS. I've noticed /dev/zram0 being configured as a swap device but I haven't researched what is actually its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. My cat /proc/swaps tells that the /dev/sda4 is being mounted, http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709854/. And mount, http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709855/, shows that all partitions are being mounted. I have read and tried about repartitioning the swap partition and adding the new uuid to /etc/fstab before but no effect.

The /dev/zram was created by casper being a dependency of remastersys.

Comment: I also notice that the error message (mountall: event failed) appears below /dev/sda1 mounting message sequence, right after it is mounted.